# How to get the function-basis as they appear in the expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, filtering, sequence, logic

I have the following expression containing functions eg. `Log`, `PolyLog` etc,

```
expr=(4 (12 (-1 + x^2) + \[Pi]^2 (1 + x^2)))/(3 (1 + x)) -
     ( 4 (1 + x^2) Log[x]^2)/(1 + x) + Log[x] (-8 (1 + x) +
     (16 (1 + x^2) Log[1 + x])/(1 + x)) + (16 (1 + x^2) PolyLog[2, -x])/(1 + x) +
     x Log[x] PolyLog[2, -x]^2;
```

I want to list all these functions (`Log`, `PolyLog`) in this expression. But I similarly want them as they appear (say a basis constructed out of these functions and their powers). In this example, the expected list will look as follows,

```
{Log[x]^2,Log[x],Log[1 + x]*Log[x],PolyLog[2, -x],Log[x] PolyLog[2, -x]^2}
```

With `Cases` I get only the distinct functions ( and their Powers ) but not multiplication,

```
Join[Cases[expr, _Log^_., -1], Cases[expr, _PolyLog^_., -1]] // Flatten // Union

{Log[x], Log[x]^2, Log[1 + x], PolyLog[2, -x], PolyLog[2, -x]^2}
```

Any suggestions? (I believe it could be done with `Cases` or `SequenceCases` but eg. `Cases[expr, _Log^_.*_PolyLog^_., -1]` does not work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the power of `*Coefficient*` functions in Mathematica, but you have to temporarily convert all your functions into "pure" symbols so that they are recognized as variables.

```
basisFunctions[expr_, funs_] := Module[{fs, map},
  fs = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, Alternatives @@ (Blank /@ funs), All];
  map = (# -> Unique[f]) & /@ fs;
  MonomialList @ 
   FromCoefficientRules[
    CoefficientRules[expr /. map, 
      fs /. map] /. ((r_ -> _) :> (r -> 1)), fs]
  ]

basisFunctions[expr, {Log, PolyLog}]
(* {Log[x]^2, Log[x] Log[1 + x], Log[x] PolyLog[2, -x]^2, Log[x], PolyLog[2, -x], 1} *)
```